# Delete data from Cassandra with part of the partition key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Let's say that I have the following table in Cassandra:

```
customer_bought_product (
    store_id uuid,
    product_id text,
    order_time timestamp,
    email text,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((store_id, product_id), order_time, email)
```

The partition keys are `store_id` and `order_id` and it is used in order to store time series data.

The data does not have a `TTL`, as it should be accessible at all times.

In some cases we may require to delete all of the data for a given `store_id`.
What is the best practice to do it?

So far I have thought of the following solutions:

1. Write a program, that will select all of the data from the table and delete the records with the given `store_id`. - The downside is that this will take more and more time as we insert more data in the table.
2. Leave the data in the table. - The only problem with doing this, is that we will have useless data.
3. Store the table name with the available partition keys in a different table, that can be queried by `store_id`, get the keys from it and create a delete statement for each or those keys. - I do not like this concept, because I have to maintain the records.

Has anyone encountered this problem? What is the best practice to clear unused records from Cassandra (excluding `TTL`)?

Comment: How can you access data with part of partition key? ALLOW FILTERING is going to be so costly and ineffective in production.

Comment: When I access the data I have a specific `product_id` and a `store_id`.

Comment: So its only during the deletes that you have just the store_id and normal access pattern is via the partition key of product_id and store_id. Have provided my answer based on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a materialized view to store the product_ids that belong to a corresponding store_ids. This way you can query the MV for a given store_id and then delete the corresponding rows from the main table. This way additional application code could be avoided to maintain two different tables.

```
create materialized view mv_customer_bought_product 
as select product_id, store_id, order_time, email 
from customer_bought_product 
where order_time is not null 
and email is not null 
and product_id is not null 
and store_id is not null 
primary key (store_id, product_id, order_time, email) ;
```

Comment: in materialized view, columns other than store_id and product_id may be excluded, this will help save disk space.

Comment: @ArunJoyThekkiniyath You need to have all columns in primary key of the main table to be present in the Materialized View as well. There is no exceptions to save storage :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using materialized views is a good solution, as I will have to maintain only one table.

Comment: The only problem that I see is that the data will not be distributed correctly leading to hotspots, as there may be stores with hundreds of products and others with thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Delete by part of partition key is not possible.

Here is one approach:

Create a separate table that will have all product_id's for a given store.

```
CREATE TABLE product_by_store(
store_id uuid,
product_id set<text>,
PRIMARY KEY(store_id)
);
```

Now wile writing to `customer_bought_product`, also update to `product_by_store`, something Like

`UPDATE product_by_store SET product_id=product_id + 'someValue' WHERE store_id=GIVEN_STORE_ID`

You can use BATCH statement while writing,this way you will get atomicity.

Now while deleting you can get all product_id for given store_id and then use

`DELETE FROM customer_bought_product WHERE store_id=GIVEN_STORE_ID and product_id in (PRODUCT_ID YOU GET from product_by_store table)`

Also delete corresponding record from `customer_bought_product`